# How to install and run PyPy on beaglebone black?

Tags: beagleboneblack, pypy

I have been stuck with this for some time now. Everytime I run ./pypy I get the error:

> ./pypy: error while loading shared libraries: /lib/libffi.so.5: file too short

I need PyPy for its JIT compiler can you guide me here? My system runs on AM335x (Beaglebone balck).

Comment: Which OS / Linux Distribution do you run? Which version of it?

Comment: @TBR Debian 8.7 kernel version  3.8.13-xenomai-r83

Comment: Sounds super old. Consider an up to date image.

Comment: @TBR Some of my application would require major upheaval if I did! Hence Im out of that option.

Comment: Something doesn't add up though. Debian Jessie does not ship libffi5. It ships libffi6 and it's not in /lib/ either. You'll probably have to expand this question with a lot of context to even start trying to understand your problem.

Comment: @TBR I did manage to set it up (used pypy-2.2-linux-armhf-raring.tar.bz2) it can run python program now when I use "pypy myprogram.py" however I dont see much difference in execution of the program. Can you guide me here?

Comment: No I can't. You are being vague about your problems at best.

Comment: Also, pypy 2.2 is ages old as well.

Comment: @TBR My current application is written by using python2.7 has execution time of around 3-4 seconds.(Im trying to speed up the execution time) I had first downloaded (pypy2-v6.0.0-linux-armhf-raspbian.tar.bz2) which asked for libffi.so.5 so I mannualy added libffi.so.5(Now I know I shouldnt have added) to that directory. Latter I removed it and added pypy-2.2-linux-armhf-raring.tar.bz2 and copied pypy to /usr/local/bin/ and sym linked it. Which got it working. When I used pypy on my application the run-time was almost similar comapred to python command. How can I speed up my execution time?

Comment: @ArminRigo Okay I now got pypy2-v5.9.0-linux-armhf-raring working.

Comment: That's ugly frankensteining. All bets are off. Instead of randomly throwing pypy at it, you might want to profile and then optimize your script. Also please don't ask me how to do this. This stackoverflow item has outlived its usefulness anyway.